# Парсинг канала с pyrogram

Tags: python, pyrogram

Имеется функция которая забирает все посты с телеграмм канала. Формат поста - 1-7 фото и текст. Функция отрабатывает но забирает один и тот же пост по 2-5 раз подряд. Видимо какой то триггер работает. Может кто в курсе как пофиксить? Чтобы выдавал каждый пост 1 раз а не по несколько раз

P.S. Сколько фото в медиа группе, столько раз этот пост и отправляется.

```
def histori_message(client: Client, message: Message):
    try:
        for message in client.get_chat_history(CHANNEL_ID):
            time.sleep(7)
            if not message.photo:
                client.send_message(my_chat_id, message.text)
            else:
                client.copy_media_group(my_chat_id, from_chat_id=CHANNEL_ID, message_id=message.id)
    except RPCError as e:
        time.sleep(60)

client.add_handler(MessageHandler(histori_message))
```